# How to capture what Alexa console sends to the endpoint?

Tags: azure, alexa-skills-kit, aws-serverless

I am currently learning about the chatbots and developed two different skills.  One has an endpoint on Azure and the other's endpoint is on AWS.  Everything works fine.  I would like to know if there is a way to see what the Alexa console sends to your endpoint (including the header)?  The Alexa console only shows the body.  I would like to capture header and body so I can test my endpoints with Postman.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> POST / HTTP/1.1
>
> Content-Type : application/json;charset=UTF-8
>
> Host : your.application.endpoint
>
> Content-Length :
>
> Accept : application/json
>
> Accept-Charset : utf-8
>
> Signature:
>
> SignatureCertChainUrl:
>   https://s3.amazonaws.com/echo.api/echo-api-cert.pem

It's the HTTP HEADER that Alexa is sending with its Body

For more info : [Request and Response JSON Reference](https://developer.amazon.com/fr/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#http-header)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have seen the JSON reference and have tried with Postman but I get a '400 NoSignatureHeader, InvalidTimestamp' response'  Why is that?  I updated the screenshot in my post.

Comment: In your endpoint you have to check several thing to check if the Json is from amazon and if it is correctly sending, the amazon certificat is not available unlimited in the time, you should check it, maybe this could help you ? -> https://philipp-guttmann.de/Blog/Alexa_Skill_Endpoint_PHP/